# Show that an equation has at most one real root in an interval

Tags: calculus

The question is as follows:

> Show that the equation $x^3 -15x +c =0$ has at most one root in the
>   interval $ [-2, 2]$

I had an idea on how to solve this problem, although it is completely different to the solution from the textbook. I hoped someone might be able to validate my working or to show me the error of my ways.

I reason that if the maxima and maxima x values of a function correspond to the roots on the graph of a derivative, then maybe the roots of a function correspond to the maximas and minimas of the graph of the derivative?

Because f(x) is continuous and differentiable on the interval, we can apply the Mean Value Theorem to the derivative of the function:

$$f''(c) =\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\ $$ 
$$ 6(c) = \frac{-3+3}{0}\ $$
$$ 6c = 1 $$
$$ c = \frac{1}{6}\ $$

Because there is only one critical value, c, it can be said that f(x) has at most one root.

Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume there are $2$ or more real roots, then by the Rolle's theorem: $f'(c) = 0$ in $[-2,2]$, but $f'(c) = 3c^2 - 15 = 3(c^2-5) < 0$ since $|c| \leq 2$. Thus it can't happen.

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. I'd be interested to know what your thought process is in approaching a problem like this? I note you proved this problem through contradiction. What made you know to prove it by contradiction and not some other way - does it just come down to intuition after doing lots of math?

Comment: Could you explain the part "by Rolle's theorem"? I don't understand why you and OP use $c$ in the equation.

Comment: Should have used another variable instead of c to avoid confusion. let the two roots in [-2, 2] be x1 and x2. That gives us an interval [x1, x2] within [-2,2] in which we can apply Rolle's theorem. Subsequently, set f'(k)=0 and you will find that the k that satisfies the the equation is outside of [-2, 2]. So we can't have two roots in [-2,2].

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)=x^3-15x+c$$

Then $$f'(x)=3x^2-15=3(x^2-5)\lt0$$ $\forall x\in[-2,2]$ since $(x^2-5)\lt0$

Thus $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $[-2,2]$ and can only have one root.